# Firebase Cloud Message Returns PERMISSION_DENIED when subscribe a topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When our service subscribes a topic we get PERMISSION_DENIED response (http status code is 200) from the iid/v1:batchAdd endpoint. The service is running on kubernetes and we use workload identity to setup service account. The service account of the service had been assigned with three roles: Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent, Firebase App Check Admin and Service Account Token Creator. That is the same roles as service account generated from firebase UI when create an private key. Here is how we create FirebaseApp in service

`

```
@Bean
  public GoogleCredentials firebaseGoogleCredentials() throws IOException {
    // default google credential is the credential of the kubernetes project
    return GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
  }

  @Bean
  public FirebaseApp firebaseApp(GoogleCredentials googleCredentials) {
    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
        .setProjectId(projectId)
        .setCredentials(googleCredentials)
        .build();
     if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
      return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } else {
      return FirebaseApp.getInstance();
    }
  }
```

Client token was generated from the same firebase project, and we can send push notification to the token from the service. Anybody know why do we get PERMISSION_DENIED error and which permission is needed except the permissions of that 3 roles.

We tried to manually generate a private key from Firebase Console, it has no problem to subscribe the topic. Only workload identity solution does not work.